# Change default zoom in QLPreviewController

Tags: pdf, zooming, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I am using a QLPreviewController to display PDF files, each page of which is a spread of a magazine. The default zoom of the QLPreview is to fill the screen by width. In portrait mode, the front and back cover, as single-pages, fill the screen, and in landscape they zoom in to fill the width, so they get cut off at the bottom. This is fine.

The two-page spreads in landscape mode zoom to fill the width as well, and as such fill the screen nicely. However, when you rotate into portrait mode, the spreads shrink down to unreadable size and leave a ton of room at the bottom of the screen.

Is there some way of changing the default zoom of this view so that the PDF will always zoom to fill the height instead of the width?

Comment: Did you get the answer ?